# AMP with amp-state and amp-position-observe

Tags: html, amp-html

I have a problem in AMP combining amp-state and amp-position-observe.

```
<amp-state id="myState">
    <script type="application/json">
        {
            "visible": "n"
        }
    </script>
</amp-state>


<amp-state id="variableChange">
    <script type="application/json">
        {
            "visible": "y"
        }
    </script>
</amp-state>

<amp-position-observer on="enter:variableChange"
        layout="nodisplay">
</amp-position-observer>
```

This code return a strange error:

```
url.js:348
Trust for 'activate' (1) insufficient (min: 100).​​​
```

Answer (score 5):

amp-position-observer currently cannot be combined with amp-state. Only amp-animation and some video components can be combined with amp-position-observer ([docs](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/master/extensions/amp-position-observer/amp-position-observer.md#what-can-i-do-with-amp-position-observer)).

Comment: Ok thanks you, i would add class to div with amp-position-observer, can i this?

Comment: @SebastianBenz is this same issue - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55101350/amp-is-it-possible-to-highlight-page-menu-on-user-scroll - can we achieve this now?

Comment: Still not possible.