# AMP: Is it possible to highlight page menu on user scroll?

Tags: scroll, amp-html

Can we highlight page menu as the user scroll down or up on the AMP page? [Here](https://codepen.io/joxmar/pen/NqqMEg) is the demo code for the same with javascript. Below is the HTML code:

```
<nav>
  <ul id="mainNav">
    <li class="active"><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#work">Work</a></li>
    <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>    
  </ul>
</nav>
<section id="home"><h2>Home</h2></section>
<section id="work" data-sr><h2>Work</h2></section>
<section id="about"><h2>About</h2></section>
<section id="contact"><h2>Contact</h2></section>
```

How can we achieve same functionality in AMP too i.e. top navigation changing automatically as the user scrolls?

Comment: I have implement on tap here : https://codepen.io/bachchasingh/pen/YgxRjJ, let me try on scroll using amp-position-observer

Comment: I don't this possible check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/48318076/5635098, hope this help you